# Hasn't the direction of Tension force been considered wrong here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

Ok so I was going through this question:

> Two small spheres of masses
> m1 and m2 are connected by a light right rod.The system is placed between a rough floor and smooth vertical wall as shown in Fig. The co-efficent of friction between the floor and the sphere of mass m2 is μ .Find the minimum value of θ so that the system of masses does not slip.

[image]

And in the solution, the following FBD was made:-
[image]

Now, I am confused about the direction of the tension force in the FBD.. As far as I know, tension force always acts "away" from the point with which it has been connected, and accordingly the Tension force (for say particle m2) should have belonged in Quadrant II,(in south east as far as 2-D FBD is considered).

Initially I assumed that since the tension force always acts "away" from the point of contact... it should have belonged in Quadrant II (for m2) and in Quadrant IV (for m1).. However the problem with this supposition was that if I suppose this , and put m2 block in equilibrium... then there will be an unbalanced downward force for m1 particle, which would mean that the particle will have to accelerate downwards.. however that is not possible as rod is inextensible.
So I came with another supposition that, for the smooth wall , maybe (just maybe, this supposition was totally unscientific to be honest but I considered it anyway) the normal force on m1 particle might be acting at a specific angle to the horizontal.. and then I tried balancing the torques... However it did not work.

So..Long story short... Why do we take the tension acting "towards" the particle?

Comment: That would be true if it were a string: in that case tension can only pull. For a rod, internal forces can act as pushing force as well.

Comment: No. Looking at the FBD, I see a force T that is pushing on m2 The x component of T balances the frictional: $Tcos(\theta) - \mu N = 0$. For m1, the y component of the T is pushing against mg: $Tsin(\theta) - m_1g = 0$ Compression instead of tension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rod is in a state of *compression* not tension.

Answer (score 2):

Tension is typically used to describe a pulling force in scenarios with cables or ropes. In such cases, tension can only pull along the length of the rope, but not push.

This problem uses a rigid rod instead of a rope, which can exert both pushing and pulling forces. The pushing force would be better called compression rather than tension, but both may only act along the length of the object.

In a dynamic problem, you could have a rigid rod that is alternately pulled under tension and pressed under compression. It would really be the same force vector acting along the rod which was changing in magnitude and direction, so it might be reasonable to call this rod force $T$, whether it was representing compression or tension at a particular point in time.

Answer (score 1):

The free body diagrams tell us that for equilibrium the rod is in compression, not tension, in order to resist the horizontal components of the normal force of the wall and the friction force of the floor.

Since the problem says the rod can be in equilibrium for some minimum $\theta$, it presumes the rod is rigid enough to withstand the compression stress, which would generally not be the case for a string or rope.

That said, I would not have labeled the force on the rod $T$ which implies the rod is in tension. Better to simply label the force in the rod $F_R$. Whether it is in tension or compression and by how much is determined by the free body diagrams and the solutions to the equations for equilibrium.

Hope this helps.